# Panning in a MFC Control using OpenGL

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, mfc

I'm very new to OpenGL so this might be a very silly question.

**What I'm using**: Visual Studio 2010, MFC framework, Windows 7.
**What I'm trying to do**: A MFC control based on OpenGL that can show some files preview with zooming, panning and rotation.
**What I've already done**:

1. Derived a class from CButton to handle all events and having a easy access to CClientDC;
2. Following a less or more recent tutorial I've encapsulated the creation of the OpenGL Device in a class.

I don't know if it's good or if I've understood what I've done, but it works.
Let me show you some code:

```
int COpenGLCtrl::OnCreate( LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct )
    {
       if( CButton::OnCreate( lpCreateStruct ) == -1 )
         return -1;
       m_pDC = new CClientDC( this );
       // This is my encapsulated device.
       m_GLDevice.Create( m_pDC->m_hDC );
       InitGL();
       return 0;
    }

    void COpenGLCtrl::InitGL( void )
    {
       glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );
       glClearColor( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    }
    // Drawing inside button.
    void COpenGLCtrl::OnPaint( void )
    {
       m_GLDevice.MakeCurrent();
       DrawGLScene();
    }
    // This function is called before DrawGLScene the first time the control is being redrawed.
    void COpenGLCtrl::ZoomOut( int nVal )
    {
       glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );  
       glLoadIdentity();
       glOrtho( 0.0f, nVal * 1.0f, 0.0f, nVal * 1.0f, nVal * 1.0f, 0.0f );
       glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
       glLoadIdentity();
    }
    void COpenGLCtrl::DrawGLScene( void )
    {
       glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
       glLoadIdentity();
       glRotatef( m_fRotation_X, 1.0f, .0f, 0.0f );
       glRotatef( m_fRotation_Y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
       glTranslatef( m_fTraslation_X, m_fTraslation_Y, 0.0f );
       glScalef( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
       glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES );
       glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
       glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
       glColor3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
       glVertex3f( 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
       glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
       glVertex3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
       glEnd();
       SwapBuffers( m_pDC->m_hDC );
    }
```

All this code is sufficient to draw a small triangle in my control with low-left vertex centered in OpenGL axis origin. All good, I showed you all this stuff to see if there are some error somewhere.
Now I want to pan around my triangle: from what I've understood, I've to modify the value of m_fTranslation_X and m_fTranslation_Y. I've decided to pan the view when the user holds down the mouse left button and moves it around:

```
void COpenGLCtrl::OnMouseMove( UINT nFlags, CPoint point )
    {
       int nRes;
       CString strOut;
       GLfloat winX, winY, winZ;
       GLint viewport[4];
       GLdouble vPos[3], modelview[16], projection[16];

       // Converting CPoint MFC coordinates to OpenGL viewport coordinates.
       m_p2dPosMouse = point;
       glGetDoublev( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview );
       glGetDoublev( GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection );
       glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, viewport );
       winX = (GLfloat)point.x;
       winY = (GLfloat)viewport[3] - (GLfloat)point.y;
       glReadPixels( point.x, int( winY ), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ );
       nRes = gluUnProject( winX, winY, winZ, modelview, projection, viewport, &vPos[0], &vPos[1], &vPos[2] );
       m_vPosMouse[0] = (GLfloat)vPos[0];
       m_vPosMouse[1] = (GLfloat)vPos[1];
       m_vPosMouse[2] = (GLfloat)vPos[2];
       if( nFlags == MK_LBUTTON )
       {
          if( !m_bTrasla )
          {
             ATLTRACE2( _T("\nInizio traslazione\n\n") );
             memcpy( m_vPosMouse_ult, m_vPosMouse, 3 * sizeof( GLfloat ) );
             m_p2dUltPos = point;
             m_bTrasla = true;
          }
          /*OPENGL-WAY
          m_fTraslation_X += m_vPosMouse[0] - m_vPosMouse_ult[0];
          m_fTraslation_Y += m_vPosMouse[1] - m_vPosMouse_ult[1];
          */
          /*MFC-WAY*/
          m_fTraslation_X += ( point.x - m_p2dUltPos.x ) / 5000.0f;
          m_fTraslation_Y += ( m_p2dUltPos.y - point.y ) / 5000.0f;
          CString   strBuf;
          strBuf.Format( _T("%f - %f || CPoint.x: %ld CPoint.y: %ld\n"), m_fTraslation_X, m_fTraslation_Y, point.x, point.y );
          ATLTRACE2( strBuf );
          ///////////////////////
          // EDIT: Added in edit to solve MFC-WAY
          m_p2dUltPos = point;
          ///////////////////////
          memcpy( m_vPosMouse_ult, m_vPosMouse, 3 * sizeof( GLfloat ) );
      }
      if( m_CB_PosAgg.Valid() )
         m_CB_PosAgg.Execute();
      Invalidate();
    }
```

In short words: I keep track of mouse last position and calculate how much I've moved on X and on Y. These differences are my traslations.
Finally my problems:

1. If I use OpenGL coordinate (commented and labelled OPENGL-WAY) the pan is smooth and precise but shakes. This is because even if my CPoint coordinates increase (or decrease) and so the difference, the OpenGL don't. Here's some values:

```
m_fTraslate_X  m_fTraslate_Y  CPoint.x CPoint.y
0.000000         0.000000        274        328
0.014377         0.141573        283        265
0.020767         0.152809        287        260
0.001597         0.002247        288        259
0.007987         0.020225        292        251
0.025559         0.164045        295        246
0.027157         0.170786        296        243
```

As you can see, while mouse control position increases (in MFC Y axis is inverted), at step 3 the values for X-axis are suddenly decreased from 0.02 to 0.002 and then back to 0.02! Why this?

**EDIT: solved in my answer.** If I use MFC coordinate, labelled MFC-WAY, I've got no shakes but a strong inertia. Sometimes happen that if I start moving my mouse to the right (assuming no up-down) then change the direction back to left, my view continues to move to the right. Where is the error?

Thanks in advance, hope you won't ban me for this noobish essay.

Comment: Go deeper, it becomes clearer :-)(joke). My test with openGL on win leads me to win32 layer, holding your win message loop yourself to keep control of everything. Consider also using your graphic card opengl library, MS openGL layer optimisation and debugging is surely not a priority for them. ( but your mistake is possibly completely something else, more simple, something that I miss)

Comment: What you mean with "MS openGL layer optimisation"?

Comment: I've read on this site today that MicroSoft strip OpenGL libs from default drivers and implement it's own OpenGL stack. To clear that point, be sure to use the OpenGL libraries provided by your graphic card manufacturer (included in the latest drivers)

Comment: Sorry, I may confuse you with my silly comments, I've not dived much into your code, but at first sight, I see nothing wrong with it

Comment: the only useful comment I could make is that camera transformations (rotation and panning) may be append to your modelview matrix, but not sure there's something wrong with your code indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem 1)**
The first problem was that when the view gets invalidated and then redrawed, the traslation has still to be performed! Solution:

```
if( nFlags == MK_RBUTTON && m_bTrasla )
{
        // Converting MFC coordinates to OpenGL System.
    ConversioneCoordinateMFC_A_OPENGL( m_vPosMouse_ult, m_p2dUltPos );
    m_fTraslation_X += m_vPosMouse[0] - m_vPosMouse_ult[0];
    m_fTraslation_Y += m_vPosMouse[1] - m_vPosMouse_ult[1];
```

**Problem 2)**
MFC-STYLE panning is not updating the last position of mouse pointer. Adding this line:

```
m_p2dUltPos = point;
```

solved the problem.

Comment: well, instinctively, I pointed you in the right direction :-)